# Update ASP.Net membership from windows service

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, windows-services, asp.net-membership

I am working on a project for a property management company.  There is the back end system that stores all of the tenants and property portfolios, and a front end website that allows users to view their packages, service requests etc.

I need to write a windows service that pulls their information out of the back end and place it into the membership database.

I cannot figure out how to configure the service to connect to the membership provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically use it as you were with the web application, they key is that you must have the same machinekey values for your application AND the web application.  Otherwise the passwords will not encrypt or decrypt in the proper manner.

Here is a tutorial that might help you out a bit on using it [from a windows app](http://www.theproblemsolver.nl/usingthemembershipproviderinwinforms.htm).  The process should be the same for your windows service.

Answer (score 0):

open up the MY PROJECT file in Solution Explorer, and then select the SERVICES tab. Check the "Enable client application services" option and basically fill in the blanks.

Alternatives, is to create a webservice which will do the processing into the membership provider for you or to have your windows service manipulate the membership data structures (assuming they're in a database or similar option) manually.