# bulk create user accounts to asp.net mvc3 membership tables in production environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership, import-from-csv

In dev environment I am using the ASP.NET configuration tool in Visual Studio to create a few users for testing. As I movel closer to QA and Production, I'm wondering what is the best way for me to automate the creation of a large amount (1000's) of users after application deployment.

I have a csv with all the usernames and passwords, roles etc. and I wan't to avail of the encryption and password salting security that is built in. I do not want to manually "Register" all these users.
I'm just not sure if this is something I can do (or instruct a db admin to perform for me).

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I would probably make a powershell script or a small console app to parse that excel and pump that into the db, and then just get rid of it. If in your console app you just add your database with EF database first, then withing seconds you have that sorted, and can get that stuff in there. You might also check into most databases having an import feature for excel files, so you might do it directly. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/72989-how-to-transfer-data-from-excel-to-db-tables/

Comment: Thanks for the comment.I've been using the aspnet_regsql.exe to generate the db on the server. I suppose I could write something to read the csv and call the register methods themselves. I was just wondering if there was a "best practice" or well established method for this type of thing.

Comment: Question: how come you want to automate a task you are only going to need to do once - or does that excel sheets data need to always be deployed again and again?

Comment: Thanks Lari, I read your original link. The thing is, I wish to invoke certain membership methods. I am not looking to simply write from the csv directly into the SQL table. I want to call Membership.CreateUser().

Comment: Yeah, I will be performing updates on this membership table on a monthly basis. New users/ delete users/ modify existing users etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to set up a "CSV Upload" form. The CSV would be processed by an MVC action calling `Membership.CreateUser` in a loop.

Probably, the performance of this will be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways that I know of approaching a batch processing problem on an ASP.NET site.

Because of the wonky way an ASP.NET site's application pool can get recycled, batch processing is usually done on an external process.

**Windows service**

One way is a separate windows service, which gets the new excel and pumps that data in, and has a timer which keeps going around. I've seen this used often, and it is quite a pain, because it takes extra work to make it easily deployable.
[Update ASP.Net membership from windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727123/update-asp-net-membership-from-windows-service)

**CacheItem**

Second way is to use CacheItems and their expiration timers to do batch processing, what you do is you define a cache object with a long timer, and when that expires and the Removed-callback gets called, you do your database work. This is good because it deploys with your ASP.NET site, and you have your code in one logical place.
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

**Workflow Foundation**

Third way, is to make a workflow foundation service. That service gets a call from your ASP.NET site, which instantiates a WF service, that does some db work with your excel file, and then it goes into a while-loop with a delay of a month in it. This is good, because it is not tied to the lifespan of your ASP.NET application pool - you get more control, and this logic can be separated into a different IIS hosted WCF service.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489452.aspx

Integrating with data is always a pain though, remember that the solution that gives you the least work and least chance of failure when deploying is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and help. I've decided I will probably go with something simple.